# MYSQL Relational Schema Planning

Tags: mysql, schema, relational

I'm trying to figure out the best way to manage this data storage problem....

I have a table of players, teams, and competitions.

A team may be involved in let's say 3 competitions.

A player belongs to a team, but may only be eligible to play in 2 of the 3 competitions that his or her team plays in. Likewise another player of the same team may be eligible for all 3.

I don't want to add a column to the player table for each competition as I'm then moving away from the relational model. Do I need another table 'competition_eligiblity' - this seems like a lot of work though!

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Alan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you do need a table for competition eligibility.

It really is no more work to put it there.  Actually, it will be less work:

- Adding a new competition in the future will be a real pain if it involves adding a new column to a table.
- If the competition eligibility is stored in columns, performing a query to get information on eligibility becomes a nightmare.

Suppose you wanted to list all the competitions players are eligible for. Here would be your query:

```
select player, "competition1" from players where competition1_eligible = 1
   union all
select player, "competition2" from players where competition2_eligible = 1
   union all
select player, "competition3" from players where competition3_eligible = 1
   union all
select player, "competition4" from players where competition4_eligible = 1
```

Sounds like fun, eh?  Whereas, if you have an eligibility table, this information will be very simple to get.

**Update:** storing all the eligibility info in a single value would be even more of a nightmare, because imagine trying to extract that information back out of the string.  That is beyond the limits of a sane SQL query.

Creating a new table is really a trivial piece of work, and you only have to do that once.  Everything after that will be much easier if you do it that way.

Comment: the other option which I know is not very elegant is to store the combinations of each competition in a single value, for example: 1=comp A and B, 2=comp A and C etc., then associate each player with one of those ids/ I know this isn't the way to go but why? I'm trying to argue against this approach but need some ammo!